# Using string name when accessing Azure Table Storage table

Tags: azure, orm, azure-table-storage

I'm using [Slazure](https://www.syssurge.com/Products/Slazure/Home.aspx) as a ORM With Azure Table Storage, my setup that works looks like this:

```
dynamic storage = new DynStorage("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
dynamic table = storage.Eopro;
```

, but now I have a table name as a string in a string variable, just how can I make it work With that:

```
    dynamic storage = new DynStorage("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
    string tableName = "Eopro";
    // ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
        dynamic storage = new DynStorage("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
        dynamic table = new DynTable(storage.StorageAccount, "Employees");
```

Will this work for you?